# Recessed light spacing

Tags: recessed-lighting

I am putting 4 inch Philips hue LED lights in my den that is 260 inches by 248 inches with 8 foot tall ceilings. I am putting 9 lights in (from scratch). The way I have it mapped out to avoid the beams and stay symmetrical it is roughly 41 inches from the walls vertical, and 47 inches from the walls horizontal. From light to light it is roughly 82 inches between (all measurements taken from the center of the light). I drew a crappy MSPaint drawing to try and help visualize: 
[image]
Is this an adequate layout? From the websites I see it says they should be about 4 foot from each other and 3 foot from the walls. The layout I have is almost 4 foot from the walls and over 6 foot from each other. Should I bring them closer together and farther from the walls? This is our main living space and I want to make sure the lighting is adequate and there is correct coverage.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be too subjective for this site, but to give you my input, I don't quite understand why people say to keep recessed lighting so far from the wall. It's supposed to be more of an accent-type light, so you really want to wash the walls, not the floor, with light, hence, move them closer to the wells. Then consider putting different types if fixtures elsewhere in the room, for example a pendant over a table or sitting area.

Comment: Agree with @PhilippNagel. But have you also considered flush mounted LED rather than recessed? You will get more light out in the room rather than pointed, spotlight effect, down to the floor.